# Probability of winning a coin draw

Tags: probability

A box contains coins that are numbered 1 through 15. Jack and Jill each take out a coin each turn, with Jack going first then Jill, without replacement. The game stops when someone draws a coin with a number that is divisible by three and that person is declared the winner.

What is the probability that Jill wins, given that the game ends on the second round?

If the coins could be replaced, what is the probability that Jack wins?

I managed to get the answer for the first part to be $\frac{13}{20}$ but I'm not so sure about the second part.

Comment: Are you sure the probability of Jill winning is so high? I don't think so.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг i found a mistake in my working, redoing it again

Comment: Since Jack takes the first round and Jill takes the second round, given that the game ended on the second round, the probability that Jill won is $100\%$.

Comment: @barakmanos Jack and Jill taking out a coin is considered as one round, I believe. Sorry if unclear. Hence to be in the second round, both Jack and Jill failed on their first try. But Jill won on her second try.

Comment: No. Each round has Jack and Jill playing one turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cases of Jack winning in the second round is the following:

He wins in the first round.

He wins in the second round, not the first. Jill doesn't win her only round.

He wins in the third round , while not winning the first two.Jill doesn't win both her rounds.

...

He wins the $n$th round without winning the previous $n-1$, and Jill doesn't win any of her $n-1$ rounds.

The probability of a win is $\frac{1}{3}$ and of a loss is $\frac{2}{3}$, because on each draw, we have $15 $ coins and $5$ multiples of $3$ out of them.

The probability of the first case is $\frac{1}{3}$ (success first round)

The probability of the second case is $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^2$ (success third round)

The probability of the third case is $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^4$ (success fifth round)

The probability of the $n$th case is $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \big(\frac{2}{3}\big)^{(2n-2)} = \frac{3}{4} \big(\frac{4}{9}\big)^n$ (success $n$th round)

So since any number of rounds can be played, we have to sum this to infinity.

$$
\frac{3}{4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{4}{9}\bigg)^n = \frac{3}{4} \frac{4}{9}\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{9}} = \frac{3}{5}.
$$

This is the probability of Jack winning in the second question. He has the advantage of going first.